# How can i bypass a CSRF protection on Website

Tags: web, csrf

I would like to receive information with a script from one page. For this purpose I have to search for a product number on the website. FOR EXAMPLE (5000112547801)

```
https://www.codecheck.info
```

First call on the Website is this one:

```
https://www.codecheck.info/product.search?q=5000112547801&r=03AGdBq25ElLW_QY-SeuWMNv0aF8pr3pttdXfqkhnosSWP_vnQDw6m0h0dK53eyf9dHe5TsKrFS0zz5NVDnHjuSclFb2CcuhSjhkndgsfBoiaQsB1w0EZR543rdA0WYsf2Y21fJl8yRQOfWsTCG-H4rlhZkBRB2Myrb_zDlYoJsUuI69LDZkCHY0g0O99fPikqeYE7Vy7_gQsIEyW8zACJF03VLppqp7ZyLeq_0Gr0IrlO1hWouITd6I6SHjezQf82BdDOnquMZQ-C2hfGNd38pP7BHJdVn-Pgvnjyo9Atl4-f4fsXSVEHSj1cGTdn5HE1MI7yu1ow8aTSvkF2k2EZKMDeBtZdPfmKy3ROWF
```

q = product code
r = crypt I cant know.

This call gives me a link to the required website.

So my questions are:
- How can i bypass the CSRF protection?
-- If not: Is there a other way to get the content automatically?
- Is there a way that i can control a normal browser via code? so the call is made with script but with a normal browser.
thanks for your attention.

Comment: You will need use paid service to resolve the captcha then use Node with Puppeteer.

Comment: Thank you:) can you recommend a service?

Comment: Use 2captcha.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is called a 'headless browser.' It'll act like a normal browser without needing to render the content.

There's multiple options for this, so select the one that best suites your needs and current language.

https://www.keycdn.com/blog/headless-browsers

If you're in Javascript world, the Node module puppeteer may be perfect for you.

https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer